# How to determine the value of the call timer or duration as displayed by the phone dialer in real-time during a call?

Tags: android, api, mobile

How do I get the duration of the call while you're IN the call?
Is it possible to programatically or is there any available Android API that can determine the value of the call timer as displayed by the phone dialer in real-time during a call (the call duration is available via the call log but this value does not appear to be updated until after the call ends).

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?